# Splitting SQL Query Result into additional columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table declared as follows

```
declare @t table(ProductCode char(25), Description char(100), Supplier char(50), ForwardOrder bit, SalesNotDelivered decimal(15,2))
```

with dummy data

```
insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('ABC', 'DescABC', 'S1', 1, 10)

insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('ABC', 'DescABC', 'S1', 0, 20)

insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('ABC', 'DescABC', 'S1', 0, 30)

insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('ABC', 'DescABC', 'S1', 0, 40)

insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('ABC', 'DescABC', 'S1', 0, 50)

insert into @t(ProductCode, Description, Supplier, ForwardOrder, SalesNotDelivered)
values ('DEF', 'DescDEF', 'S2', 0, 500)
```

I want to sum the SalesNotDelivered column but split it into two in the result set - one column showing the sum of Forward Orders, the other the sum of non forward orders

So using the data above I would end up with:-

```
ProductCode    Description   Supplier   SalesNotDelivered   SalesNotDeliveredFwdOrders
ABC            DescABC       S1         140                 10
DEF            DescDEF       S2         500                 0
```

What is the most efficient query to do this?

Comment: what query have you written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you need a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression with [GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause

```
SELECT ProductCode, [Description], Supplier,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ForwardOrder <> 1 THEN SalesNotDelivered END), 0) AS SalesNotDelivered,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ForwardOrder = 1 THEN SalesNotDelivered END), 0) AS SalesNotDeliveredFwdOrders          
FROM @t
GROUP BY ProductCode, [Description], Supplier
```

Demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25220)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it would be somewhat like

```
SELECT 
ProductCode, Description,Supplier, 
SUM(SalesNotDelivered) as SalesNotDelivered,
SUM(ForwardOrder)as SalesNotDeliveredFwdOrders 
FROM t 
GROUP BY
Supplier
```